# How do I compute the probability in this exercise?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I need to define the probability space $\Omega$  and it's probability function $\Bbb{P}$ for the following exercise:

> For a fair die which we toss two times, compute the probability that the parity of the two numbers that show up matches.

My Idea was the following. We define $\Omega=\{1,...,6\}^2$, then $|\Omega|=36$. We have the following partition into even and odd numbers:$$\Omega=\{1,3,5\}~\dot\cup~\{2,4,6\}=:A~\dot \cup ~B$$Now let us define $\Lambda\subset \Omega$ such that it contains all pairs $(u,v)$ where $u,v\in A$ or $u,v\in B$.

1. Case $1$: $u,v\in A$. Then we have $3^2=9$ possibilities.
2. Case $2$: $u,v\in B$. Then we have $3^2=9$ possibilities.

Thus we have $18$ possibilities and $$\Bbb{P}(\Lambda)=\frac{|\Lambda|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{18}{36}=\frac{1}{2}$$ Is this correct so?

Comment: Yes: it is correct.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Comment: More generally, if $\Omega$ is finite, define $\mathbf{P}$ just as here. It will be a consistent probabilty measure.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment but it seems to be interesting, could you maybe explain this a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine overall!

One suggestion: you might be a bit more explicit about what the measure $\mathbb P$ is actually defined to be. It's not hard, of course -- it just assigns a measure of $1/36$ to each of the $36$ atomic elements (i.e. single pairs). I think it'd be good to specify that for completeness' sake, since in principle you could construct an alternative probability measure that might correspond to, say, rolling weighted dice. Additionally, you were apparently asked to construct the probability measure, and your posted solution sees to just *use* it without ever stopping to say how it's defined.

That said, that comment is a bit nitpicky. The probability measure you have implicitly chosen is, in any reasonable sense, the default one.

Comment: @AronMontgomery sorry we have not spoken yet about the probability measure we only have defined the probabilita $\Bbb{P}(\Lambda)=\frac{|\Lambda|}{|\Omega|}$. But it sounds really interesting, so could you maybe explain how we get to this measure and what the connection is?

Comment: The probability measure is a function that should take in subsets of $\Omega$ and map them into $[0, 1]$ (and satisfy other various properties, such as that $\mathbb P(\Omega) = 1$). In short, it's supposed to say how to assign probabilities to outcomes or groups of outcomes. To illustrate: suppose you had dice that landed on 1 half the time (and the other outcomes $10\%$ of the time). In that case, you'd want to use $\mathbb P$ to assign different probabilities to the pairs $(1, 1)$, $(1, 5)$, and $(5, 5)$ -- specifically, those pairs' probabilities would be $0.25, 0.05, 0.01$ respectively.

Comment: As a second example: consider a coin flip. The states could be $\{H, T\}$, but there are lots of ways that we could assign probabilities. A fair coin would have $\mathbb P(H) = \mathbb P(T) = 0.5$. A biased coin might have $\mathbb P(H) = 0.9, \mathbb P(T) = 0.1$. The important bit is that the state space is the same, but we can modify how we specify the probability to model various phenomena. Note that when your state space is finite, it suffices to just specify what $\mathbb P$ should be on each individual element of $\Omega$; no need to specify $\mathbb P$ on the entirety of $2^{\Omega}$.

Comment: The probability measure that you've talked about so far is the so-called *discrete uniform* measure, and it's a particularly important and special one. You could probably specify in your answer by just restating that you're using the measure $\mathbb P(\Lambda) = \frac{|\Lambda|}{|\Omega|}$ as you did earlier..

Comment: ah so my $\Bbb{P}$ is a function $\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ sending a subset $\Lambda$ to the quotient $\frac{|\Lambda|}{|\Omega|}$? And this is a measure calling the discrete uniform measure right? so it satisfy clearly that $\Bbb{P}(P)=1$, $\Bbb{P}(X)\geq 0$ and $\Bbb{P}(\cup X_i)=\sum_i \Bbb{P}(X_i)$ right?

Comment: Exactly! ${}{}{}$

Comment: ah wow perfect thanks, thats really interesting! And then we can define different measures right? but is there a way to see which measure we need in a specific situation

Comment: So I mean as you wrote we can take $\Bbb{P}=0.5$ or $0.9$ which gives completly different results

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

When you define the sample space, it is very helpful if each element in the space is equally likely.  Within this parameter, you could simplify the problem by defining the sample space to have only $4$ elements, instead of $36$ elements.

Let $E$ be the event that the die roll is even. 
Let $O$ be the event that the die roll is odd.

Then, you could define the sample space to be

$\{E,O\}^2~$ (four elements)

Here, the favorable outcomes would be the union of $\{E\}^2$ (one element) with $\{O\}^2$ (one element).

So, the probability would be computed as

$$\frac{1 + 1}{4}.$$

The underlying idea behind this alternative approach is that the problem asks you to focus (only) on the die's odd/even parity on each of the  two rolls.  This can be (validly) done without focusing on the (exact) number of spots face-up on the die rolls.